# How to update an editItemTemplate checkboxlist from codebehind?

Tags: asp.net

I am using a gridview fed from a SQL database. I need to add a custom itemTemplate that will consist of a checkboxlist fed from another datasource. Here is my xml part :

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Equipements" >
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="myCB" runat="server">
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

I am using the gridview onEditing event to try to access "myCB" in the code behind :

```
    protected void OnEditing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gridview = sender as GridView;
        GridViewEditEventArgs  editEvent = e as GridViewEditEventArgs;
        ListViewItemEventArgs rowEvent = e as ListViewItemEventArgs;
        TableCell equipementsCell = gridview.Rows[editEvent.NewEditIndex].Cells[11];

        CheckBoxList equipements = gridview.Rows.FindControl("myCB") as CheckBoxList;
    }
```

This code doesn't work, the checkboxlist isn't found. I have tried many things unsuccessfully...

Comment: have you looked in `gridview.FindControl("myCB")`

Answer (score 0):

You should use GridView's [`RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType  == DataControlRowType.DataRow
    &&  e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
    {
        CheckBoxList equipements = (CheckBoxList )e.Row.FindControl("myCB"); 
        equipements.DataSource = getSomeData();
        equipements.DataTextField = "TextColumn"; 
        equipements.DataTextField = "IdColumn";
        equipements.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: could he use the RowEditing event with `(CheckBoxList)gridview.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("myCB")` to locate and bind a datasource to the list?

Comment: @MrZulu: Edited my answer. I've missed the `EditItemTemplate` part totally.